# Wordpress - Uploading the featured image for a post programatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a script that allows me to set the featured image of a certain post. For some reason it is not working. Could anyone tell me why?

```
$post_id = ... // We get the ID from the form

if (isset($_FILES['thumbnail'])) {
    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['userfile'];
    $filename      = $uploaded_file['name'];
    $tmp_file      = $uploaded_file['tmp_name'];
    $upload_dir    = wp_upload_dir();
    $end_file      = $upload_dir['path']."/$filename";

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $end_file);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $end_file, $post_id);
    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
}
```

Comment: why are you not using the ui for adding featured image section when you create new post?

Comment: I have to create an interface to do this, withouth access to the native WP backend. Of course, I would prefer to do it that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the correct param name which keeps the file uploaded?

You are using different param name in If statement and just next line:

```
if (isset($_FILES['thumbnail'])) {
    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['userfile'];
```

So just make sure it s pulling the file info from the correct param.
Also, you are passing incorrect file path for following code:

```
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
```

It should be `$end_file`, instead of `$filename`.

So the correct code might look like following:

```
$post_id = ... // We get the ID from the form

if (isset($_FILES['thumbnail'])) {
    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['userfile'];
    $filename      = $uploaded_file['name'];
    $tmp_file      = $uploaded_file['tmp_name'];
    $upload_dir    = wp_upload_dir();
    $end_file      = $upload_dir['path']."/$filename";

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $end_file);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($end_file, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $end_file ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $end_file, $post_id);

    // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $end_file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
}
```

Comment: Turns out, that was the problem... I was using the wrong string to identify the file... Sorry. It is quite silly bug... 8-(

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent no worries at all. Bug is just the bug, every one makes the bug, so no worries at all. :-)

Comment: Thanks mate. Saved me hours ;)